# Custom STM32H7 board + LAN8742 ethernet problem

Tags: pcb-design, stm32, ethernet, st

I develop custom board with STM32H743VIT6 with ethernet LAN7842.
When I plug ethernet, leds are not blinking. Is it hardware problem? When I plug eth to erased NucleoH7 board leds always blink.

My code on devboard NucleoH743ZI (with ethernet communication) work properly, but after port to STM32H743VI (custom board) get HAL_ERROR from HAL_ETH_Init() on this code:

```
  /* Ethernet Software reset */
  /* Set the SWR bit: resets all MAC subsystem internal registers and logic */
  /* After reset all the registers holds their respective reset values */
  SET_BIT(heth->Instance->DMAMR, ETH_DMAMR_SWR);

  /* Get tick */
  tickstart = HAL_GetTick();

  /* Wait for software reset */
  while (READ_BIT(heth->Instance->DMAMR, ETH_DMAMR_SWR) > 0U)
  {
    if(((HAL_GetTick() - tickstart ) > ETH_SWRESET_TIMEOUT))
    {
      /* Set Error Code */
      heth->ErrorCode = HAL_ETH_ERROR_TIMEOUT;
      /* Set State as Error */
      heth->gState = HAL_ETH_STATE_ERROR;
      /* Return Error */
      return HAL_ERROR;
    }
  }
```

Where should I look for the problem?

---

Actualization!
I replaced my 25Mhz quartz with quartz from out of order H7 devboard.
Now after board powering both led are blinking once every second.
When I reset LAN7842 with pin, my PC detect the connection and yelow led are blinking fast (green off).
Now i will try ping board, and connect to mqtt.
But why I should reset LAN/STM after powering to make connection?

---

Next step,
I make connection with MQTT and can ping my board from PC, but i have a problem with connection stability. Ping is sometimes unresponsive (about once in 10 queries). MQTT disconnect from broker during transmission every 5ms. If the transmission is slower, it does not drop the connection, but the ping sometimes does not respond. On ethernet connector green led is always off and yellow is blinking fast(even when no data is being transferred).
I tested the same program on devboard and everything is ok (green ledd is always on and yellow blink during transmission).
Have You any idea what can be wrong ?

Comment: If not even LED's connected to LAN8742 light up when connecting the cable, then probably the LAN8742 has some hardware issue. Start by verifying all supply voltages, reset-signal and oscillator on the LAN8742.

Comment: Did you copy paste the schematics or maybe there is an error? Post schematics.

Comment: @Justme, I did not design from scratch, but I followed the diagram from the Nucleo board from ST. All components, paths and soldering points appear correct.
My scheme: [LINK](https://imgur.com/a/MDRQJDU)

Comment: Actualization! I replaced my 25Mhz quartz with quartz from out of order H7 devboard. Now after board powering both led are blinking once every second. When I reset LAN7842 with pin, my PC detect the connection and yelow led are blinking fast (green off). Now i will try ping board, and connect to mqtt. But why I should reset LAN/STM after powering to make connection?

Answer (score 1):

You have built a circuit with discrete transformer which requires a simple connector.

However instead of a simple connector your circuit has a magjack, a connector with built-in magnetics.

Even if the Ethernet link could form via two sets of transformers, it will not do so as the connections between magjack and discrete magnetics are mixed up badly. The magjack pinout will not match the connector pinout.

And after your edit about schematics not matching your design, and about needing a reset, I append the following:

Datasheet says the LAN8742 requires a reset after power-up.

The datasheet does not say why, it just says it is required, so it's enough of a reason to reset the chip after powering, and there is no reason to assume it works without a reset then.

Comment: My bad, i forgot mention. You have right that in schematic is magjack but I use simple RJ45 socket. Pinout is the same like on devboard.